# COUNTIFS not returning correct count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with two tabs: Output and Data. Output has a layout of results/aggregations and data has the information I used. I want to count all instances of two texts in a Data column and return that in Output but my formula is not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

In this example, the value from the formula in C2 of Output sheet should be two since there were two resources created in January of 2021 as per the Data sheet.

Data Sheet

[image]

Output Sheet

[image]

Comment: Use Wild Cards: `=COUNTIFS(Data!B:B,"*"&A3&"*",Data!B:B,"*"&B3&"*")`

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: @ScottCraner It worked. Thanks for this. For future reference, I am wondering why it worked?

Comment: Without the wild cards it is looking for a complete match and since there is other text beside the two you are looking for you need to use wildcards to indicate a partial match is desired.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(Data!B:B, "*"&D2:D21&"*", Data!B:B, "*"&E2:E21&"*"))
```

[image]